# How to automatically open the location list window after using the :lhelpgrep command?

Tags: autocmd, quickfix

I have the following autocmds to automatically open the quickfix window or the location list window after executing a quickfix command.

```
augroup quickfix_window
    autocmd!
    autocmd QuickFixCmdPost [^l]* nested cwindow | setlocal nowrap | redraw!
    autocmd QuickFixCmdPost l* nested lwindow | setlocal nowrap | redraw!
augroup END
```

It seems to work except with the `:lhelpgrep` command.

If I type `:lvim /autocmd/ %` to look for all the words matching `autocmd` inside the current buffer, the location list is populated with all the matches and the location list window is automatically opened (provided there are matches).

But If I type `:lh autocmd` to look for the word `autocmd` inside the help files, even though the command is run and the location list is populated with results, the location list window is not opened, I have to do it manually with `:lwindow`.

According to `:h QuickFixCmdPre`, `The pattern is matched against the command being run.`.

Here the command name is `:lh` which begins with the `l` character, so it should match the pattern `l*` in the 2nd autocmd.

If I replace `:lwindow` with `:lopen`, the previous command `:lh autocmd` raises the following error:

```
Error detected while processing QuickFixCmdPost Auto commands for "l*":
E776: No location list
```

It seems `:lh` populates the location list after the `QuickFixCmdPost` event, instead of before like I expected.  Is it normal?
Is there another way to make the location list window automatically opened after `:lh` has been run?

Comment: Your problem is elsewhere: `lhelpgrep` opens a help window, and the `loclist` is associated to the help window, not the window you're starting from.

Comment: @SatoKatsura You're right, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [Sato Katsura](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8327/how-to-automatically-open-the-location-list-window-after-using-the-lhelpgrep-co#comment13986_8327), I've realised that I was wrong, `:lh` does not populate the location list after the `QuickFixCmdPost` event, but before like it should.

The problem is that `:lh foobar` (contrary to `:lvim /foobar/ %`) creates a help window (if we aren't already in one) to display the first match of our search.
The location list populated by `:lh` is associated to this newly created window not to the one where we initially typed `:lh foobar`.

This causes a problem for an autocmd. Because, when the `QuickFixCmdPost` event is triggered, the help window hasn't been created by `:lh` yet.
So, `:lwindow` will fail, because there's no location list associated to the current window. A possible solution would be to delay the execution of `:lwindow` (10ms should be enough).

There may a better way of doing it, but for the time being, I've come up with this:

```
augroup quickfix_window
    autocmd!
    autocmd QuickFixCmdPost [^l]* nested cwindow | setlocal nowrap | redraw!
    autocmd QuickFixCmdPost l[^h]* nested lwindow | setlocal nowrap | redraw!
    autocmd QuickFixCmdPost lhelpgrep nested call timer_start(10, s:snr() . 'lh_lwindow')
augroup END

fu! s:lh_lwindow(id) abort
    lwindow
    setlocal nowrap
    redraw!
endfu

fu! s:snr()
    return matchstr(expand('<sfile>'), '<SNR>\d\+_')
endfu
```

It delays the execution of the `:lwindow` command for 10ms when the quickfix command is `:lhelpgrep`, which should give enough time for the help window to be created.